# Shell script to compare remote directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, diff

I have a shell script that I am using to compare directory contents. The script has to ssh to different servers to get a directory listing. When I run the script below, I am getting the contents of the server that I am logged into's /tmp directory listing and not that of the servers I am trying to ssh to. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? 
The config file used in the script is as follows (called config.txt):

```
server1,server2,/tmp
```

The script is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
CONFIGFILE="config.txt"
IFS=","
while read a b c
do
    SERVER1=$a
    SERVER2=$b
    COMPDIR=$c
    `ssh user@$SERVER1 'ls -l $COMPDIR'`| sed -n '1!p' >> server1.txt
    `ssh user@$SERVER2 'ls -l $COMPDIR'`| sed -n '1!p' >> server2.txt
done < $CONFIGFILE
```

When I look at the outputs of server1.txt and server2.txt, they are both exactly the same - having the contents of /tmp of the server the script is running on (not server1 or 2). Doing the ssh +dir listing on command line works just fine. I am also getting the error "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal". Adding the -t -t to the ssh command isnt helping either
Thank you

Comment: use something like `dirdiff` or if you'd rather, there's a very nice `DirDiff` plugin for ViM.

Comment: @AlexejMagura, I do not/ cannot install any plugins. My issue is with the ssh command. It is doing a listing of /tmp of the host that is running the script and not the remote host I am intending to run the ls command on

Comment: Why do you have backticks around the ssh command?

Comment: turn on `set -vx` to debug/trace your script. You need to see that `/tmp` is inside the cmd sent to `ssh user@host`, its just a matter of getting the quoting right. Your posted question obscures your problem, boil it down to something someone could execute from their cmd line. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, On the command line,
 ssh user@$SERVER1 'ls -l /tmp' executes just fine. Also I added the keys etc and am not prompted for a password.I have the back ticks in order to execute the command.

Comment: if you're getting the results of the local /tmp dir in your script, that definitely means that your quoting is off. You can't escape a singlequote inside single quotes, so you have to build up un-quoted single quotes with with something like `'"'"'` (instead of just `\'` as you might think). Good luck.

Comment: See: [How to diff and merge two directories?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/778/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 0):

> I have the back ticks in order to execute the command.

Backticks are not needed to execute a command - they are used to expand the standard output of the command into the command line. Certainly you don't want the output of your `ssh` commands to be interpreted as commands. Thus, it should work fine without the backticks:

```
    ssh user@$SERVER1 "ls -l $COMPDIR" | sed -n '1!p' >>server1.txt
    ssh user@$SERVER2 "ls -l $COMPDIR" | sed -n '1!p' >>server2.txt
```

(provided that double quotes to allow expansion of `$COMPDIR` are used).

Answer (score -1):

first you need to generate keys to login to remote without keys

```
ssh-keygen  -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

then try to ssh without pass

```
ssh remote-host
```

then try to invoke in your script but first make sanity check

```
var1=$(ssh remote-host) die "Cannot connect to remote host" unless $var1;
```

Comment: I can login just fine to the remote machine. It's just that the ls is being run locally rather than on the remote server. On the command line, the ssh+ls works fine.

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to the fact that the $COMPDIR is not being evaluated within ssh user@$SERVER1 'ls -l $COMPDIR'. Is there a reason for this? Would you be able to tell me how I can pass a directory name in it's place?

Comment: I added the following and now the ls executes remotely
     ssh npandit@$SERVER1<<ENDSSH
       FILES=`ls -l $COMPDIR`
    ENDSSH
        echo $FILES >> "1.txt"
But how do i get the list of files to be written to a local file?